# Yosemite... & lack of backup

Tags: discussion, yosemite, fun

Is there some prescribed response to "I put a beta on my machine, with no backup at all & now I broke it" ... other than giggling, of course.

Comment: Only giggling? that is a restrained response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prescribed response is to flag it for closure for being about pre-release software and/or hardware.

And you can point them to: [Can I downgrade to Mavericks after installing Yosemite (beta/developer preview)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135677/can-i-downgrade-to-mavericks-after-installing-yosemite)